# Errors when adding C libraries to a project with ARC

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to use a set of C libraries to allow custom graphs in my iOS project. My projects uses ARC, however, the custom graph libraries are based on a project that does not use ARC. The errors I am getting are related to ARC.

The documentation for the C libraries specify that when using the library to turn off ARC. However, my project is too evolved to revert to a non ARC project.

How might I still use this library in my project? The library is PowerPlot.

Comment: If the library documentation tells you to turn off ARC, your option is to turn off ARC or not use the library.

Comment: @nhgrif false. Read below.

Comment: The answer that starts with "You can turn off ARC"?

Comment: @nhgrif *turn off ARC*, and *turn off ARC for the specific library* are fairly different concepts. Especially when the OP is saying *my project is too evolved to revert to a non ARC project*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn off ARC for the specific library, by adding the `-fno-objc-arc` compiler flag.

Go in your Target Settings > Build Phases > Compile Sources, and add the compiler flag to every implementation file from the library.

Further information can be found here: [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Comment: Minor typo. Should be `-f`

Comment: I fixed it while you were typing probably. It should be ok now ;)